# Почему при наследовании обьект поле берется из одного класса а метод из другого?

Tags: java

```
class Test extends A {
  int i=1;

  void doit(){
      System.out.println(" class Test");
  }

  public static void main(String...args){
      A c=new Test();
      System.out.println(c.i);
      c.doit();
  }
}

class A {
    int i=2;

    void doit(){
      System.out.println("class A");
    }
}

  //2
  //class Test
```

Comment: Потому что нельзя так делать, надо использовать инкапсуляцию

Answer (score 1):

Хотя в объекте типа `Test` два поля `i`, когда ссылка, указывающая на этот объект, имеет тип `A`, обращение `c.i` относится к `i` из класса `A`, так как `Test.i` компилятору не виден.

Поскольку все (не `private`) методы экземпляра класса в Java - виртуальные, вызывается переопределенный метод `Test.doit` - так как тип созданного объекта все-таки `Test`.

Comment: Можно еще добавить, что статические методы, как и переменные, вызываются у родительского класса.

Comment: @Vennic Я лучше напишу "методы экземпляра класса".

Answer (score 1):

В Java, при наследовании, переменной имеющей тип суперкласса (родителя) может быть присвоена ссылка на любой тип подкласса (наследника). В данном примере тип "А" является суперклассом, а "Test" - его подклассом. Особенность заключается в том, что доступные поля класса определяются именно типом ссылочной переменной.

```
 A c = new Test();
```

В данном случае переменная "с" имеет тип суперкласса "А", хотя и ссылается на тип "Test". Соответственно в объекте "с" будет доступна переменная i именно из суперкласса, т.е. родителя. Поле i из подкласса "Test" в объекте "с" просто не видно.
    Что касается методов - при наследовании, если сигнатура метода подкласса совпадает с методом суперкласса, то метод подкласса (потомка) переопределяет (можно сказать "заменяет") метод суперкласса (предка). В данном случае методы `doit()` в суперклассе "А" и в подклассе "Test" совпадают, соответственно в объекте "с" вызывается метод `doit()` именно класса "Test".